# How to click on recycle view item by checking the toolbar name?

Tags: android

Title says it all, here is my `onBindViewHolder`:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final AreaAdaptor.MyViewHolder holder, final int position) 
{
    final AreaAlbum album = albumList.get(position);
    Glide.with(mContext).load(album.getThumbnail()).into(holder.thumbnail);
    holder.title.setText(album.getName());
    holder.thumbnail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (toolbar.getTitle().toString().equals("Maharashtra")) {
                if (position == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MaharashtraDetail.class);
                    intent.putExtra("AreaName", position);**strong text**
                    *mContext.startActivity*(intent);
                }
                ...
            }
            ...
        }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The required behavior is not exactly clear. However, if you want to set the click listener on the entire item you can use `RecyclerView.ViewHolder.itemView`:

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {...}
    }
```

Comment: i want to click the recycle view position by checking toolbar name. Suppose it check if toolbar is equal to Science then it click the position and if toolbar is equal is to commerce then it click position according to that

Comment: What you can do is set a value inside the adapter when you set the title in the toolbar and perform the click according to that value. Alternately, you can try to access the toolbar (through your activity) and get that value to do the same. In any event, the onClick() can be the same and you don't have to change it.

Comment: when i click on the recycle View item then it give me the same detail for every item

Comment: it show me some error when i try to post my code here... can i mail you...if you don't have any problem????

Comment: We can chat here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137479/how-to-click-on-recycle-view-item-by-checking-the-toolbar-name